# Displaying hierarchical data from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working the front end of a project tasked with displaying some data that is organized as hierarchical in the database. I've yet to work with these kind of data types and my first go-to was gridview which only displayed the "parent" and none of the data beneath. I've googled several options but most look like they use ADO.NET or Linq to query the database whereas I need an option for the back-end that is implemented with the entity framework. My back end dev has set up this method to return the asset data:

```
public List<AssetEntity> GetAllAssets()
{
    List<AssetEntity> getAllAssets = dal.SelectAsset(1);
    Error = dal.Error;
    return getAllAssets;
}
```

A treeview sounds like my best option but I'm not sure what control or how to implement this with EF. Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying a tree in html can be accomplished by nested unordered lists:

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li><div>Item 1</div></li>
    <li><div>Item 2</div></li>
    <li><div>Item 3</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>Item 3.1</div></li>
            <li><div>Item 3.2</div>
                 <ul>
                    <li><div>Item 3.2.1</div></li>
                    <li><div>Item 3.2.2</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Some css to make it look more tree-like:

```
ul
{
    list-style:none;
    /*list-style-image: url('your_image_url_here')*/
}
```

And jQuery to Expand/Collapse child-nodes on click:

```
$(function(){
    $(".tree li div").click(function()
        {
            var children = $(this).parent("li").children("ul");
            if(children.length > 0)
            {
                if(children.is(":visible"))
                {
                   children.hide();
                }
                else
                {
                   children.show();
                }
            }   
        });
});
```

Full sample: http://jsfiddle.net/eQxTs/5/

You can render the list in razor by using Partial Views or DislayTemplates for each list of AssetEntity. By iterating over the child collection with the same PartialView in each AssetEntity You will get the recursion to make it a tree.

Razor:

```
@model IEnumerable<AssetEntity>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
       <li>@item.Name
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Children)
       </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: I've added some css and jQuery to complete the sample.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't use razor? I'm afraid I'm not up to speed with that just yet. I've been using standalone .aspx pages to display. I will give this a whirl though.

Comment: As long as we are still talking about mvc and not webforms, the idea of PartialViews or DisplayTemplates remains the same. Anyhow I would encourage you to give the razor viewengine a try. It's like "Just put an @sign and do some c# ...". I started it with this reference: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: Edit: I'm using webforms

The back end dev is the one using EF. I'm just pulling it through the form using basic C# and webform controls

Comment: Ok, I was mislead by the mvc tag on your question ;-). But I'm pretty sure there are be similar solutions in webforms.