# How do I make a list of categories with several subcategories?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a View which contains a list of categories. These categories have a subcategories and some subcategories also have subcategories.

In the memory I have a list of Categorie objects.

My Categorie object:

```
namespace modellen
{
    public class Categorie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Naam { get; set; }
        public int HoofdCategorieId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My view:

```
@using modellen
@model List<Categorie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Categorieen";
}

<h2>Categorieen</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (Categorie c in Model)
    {
        if (c.HoofdCategorieId == 0)
        {
            <li>@c.Naam </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

If the property "HoofdCategorieId" of an object is 0, it means it is NOT a subcategory of anything. If the property "HoofdCategorieId" is 2 for example, it means that it is a subcategory of an object where the property "Id" is also 2.

I can't figure out how How would continue from here to make the subcategories appearing below each respective category.

How would I do this?

Comment: Using the answer from [Displaying hierarchical data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22666357/205233) would allow an arbitrary nesting depth but will require to change your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (Categorie c in Model.Where(w => w.HoofdCategorieId == 0))
{
    <li>@c.Naam </li>
    foreach (Categorie subC in Model.Where(w => w.HoofdCategorieId == c.Id))
    {
        <li style="margin-left:10px;">@subC.Naam </li>
        foreach (Categorie subSubC in Model.Where(w => w.HoofdCategorieId == subC.Id))
        {
            <li style="margin-left:20px;">@subSubC.Naam </li>

        }
    }
}
```

use `Where` from linq to loop through the items you want

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string CategoryName {get; set;}
public int SubcategoryId {get; set;}
public IEnumerable<Subcategory> Subcategories {get; set;}
```

And second model

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string SubcatecoryName {get; set;}
public int CategoryId {get; set;}
public Category Category {get; set;}
```

This is one to many or many to one
Id are navigation properties.
Then in view
Foreach(var item in model)
Categories
From categories can take subcategories